# TVS Array Clamping With IO Less than Standoff Voltage

Tags: tvs, clamp

I have 2 IO lines one at +3.000V and the other at -3.000V.  They do not turn on simultaneously. Both Voltage levels are off a precision <1%LDO

Both lines are connected to a bidirectinoal TVS (TPD4E02B04 Pin1/Pin2) which has +/-3.6V Working Voltage.

The moment I have both IOs "ON" ie Active +/- 3.0V the TVS clamps both tho 2.8V and starts sinking current.

Is there a reason for this?  I dont see why this should clamp under +/-3.6V and would really appreciate the explanation.

To clarify. This only happens once I have both pos and neg signals active.  I can turn them on in any order and delay and it still clamps. I can have each individual signal enable with no clamping.

My initial idea is the +/- active combined to crate a 6v Delta but the gnd connection is solid at the tvs

Comment: Can you draw a schematic of exactly how you have the TVS diodes hooked up?

Comment: Click edit to edit your post, and a button along the top row is a schematic editor.

Comment: Does the TVS  clamp *both* lines to 2.8V or the +3.0V line to +2.8V and the -3.0V line to -2.8V?

Comment: The tvs clamps both lines to -2.8 and +2.8 respectively. When it starts to conduct. 

I have verified with a scope that neither signals get anywhere near +/-3.6v.  I also have other tvs in the design that don't clamp even with 3.3v levels.  The only difference is this TVS also has the -3v

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet has been silently updated:

[TI document SLVSD85–NOVEMBER 2015](https://datasheet.octopart.com/TPD4E02B04DQAR-Texas-Instruments-datasheet-59814757.pdf) shows one orderable device, `TPD4E02B04DQAR`, with a minimum activation voltage listed as `6.7v` and no further details.

[TI document SLVSD85A–NOVEMBER 2015–REVISED FEBRUARY 2016](https://datasheet.octopart.com/TPD4E02B04DQAR-Texas-Instruments-datasheet-62283090.pdf) shows the same device, `TPD4E02B04DQAR` but with much more detail. It lists a *lower* minimum activation voltage of `5.5v`. In section 6.3 Recommended Operating Conditions, it lists \$V_{IO}\$ Input pin voltage as –3.6v to +3.6v and the same with \$V_{RWM}\$ reverse stand-off voltage.

Since these TVS's are ground-referenced, whichever one(s) are conducting must be experiencing a spike beyond +/-3.6v. The \$V_{BRF}\$ and \$V_{BRR}\$ Forward and Reverse Breakdown Voltage (any IO pin to GND) is specified as +/-6.4v nominal, but could be as low as +/-5.5v.

So there must be a spike beyond +/-5.5v on the affected lines. If you use an oscilloscope to probe them, be sure to use a 10x or even 100x probe for greater bandwidth and reduced loading. A fast 'scope may be needed.

Short of that, you could try temporarily adding a little capacitance to these lines to prevent a fast spike from tripping them. Something like 20pF might do it. Of course, this will slow down fast data edges, so if high-speed data is on those lines, it may be affected.

Comment: I have verified with a scope (>18Gig samples) that neither signals get anywhere near +/-3.6v.  So I know I'm not missing a n impulse   I also have other tvs in the design that don't clamp even with 3.3v levels.  The only difference is this TVS also has the -3v

Comment: Have you tried a new TPD4E02B04DQAR? (Also since these are unpolarized, rotate it 180° to see if there is any difference when using the *other two* TVS's.) The datasheet lists no stipulations or limitations to using differential voltages. I'd still tack a tiny SMT cap across the affected traces just to see if lowpass filtering affects it. If that proves nothing and you're absolutely sure Vbrf/brr is not being violated, I'd contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Yes I am 100% certain I have 6 other boards with the same issue